# Is there any way to create DB2 database having name length of more than 8 characters

Tags: db2

I have installed DB2 v11.1.x.
So is it possible to create a database with name size more than 8 characters

Answer (score 0):

The answer , for Db2-LUW version 11.x is **NO** , the maximum length of a database name is 8 bytes.

This is documented on the page ["SQL and XML Limits"](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.1?topic=sql-xml-limits) with the wording:

```
Description                     Maximum length in bytes
Server (database alias) name    8
```